# In terraform for aws_ecs_service how do we set Service Set Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In Terrafrom when creating ecs services how do we define auto Scaling services. I do not see resoruce aws_ecs_service having the option.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

ECS auto scaling is managed by [Application Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html). Thus, to set it up for your ECS service you have to use:

- [aws_appautoscaling_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_target) - example for ECS in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_target#ecs-service-autoscaling).
- [aws_appautoscaling_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_policy) - example for ECS in [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_policy#ecs-service-autoscaling) as well.